# Find the centroid of Clusters generated by the hclust function

Tags: r

I need to get the centroid for each cluster computed by the hierarchical method.
First, this is a part of my dataset to get reproductible example:

```
> dput(DATABASE[1:20,])
structure(list(TYPE_PEAU = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L), SENSIBILITE = c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L), IMPERFECTIONS = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), BRILLANCE = c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), GRAIN_PEAU = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), RIDES_VISAGE = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), MAINS = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), PEAU_CORPS = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), INTERET_VACANCES = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT = c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), AGE_INTERVAL = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), ATTENTE_BEAUTE_1 = c(1L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
4L, 6L, 3L), ATTENTE_BEAUTE_2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MILIEU_VIE = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), PROFIL_SELECTIONNE = c(1L, 32L, 21L, 23L, 34L, 31L, 
15L, 6L, 1L, 20L, 14L, 34L, 9L, 28L, 28L, 32L, 42L, 20L, 32L, 
14L), NOMBRE_ACHAT = c(14L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 10L, 14L, 4L, 
3L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 3L), NOMBRE_CADEAU = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("TYPE_PEAU", "SENSIBILITE", "IMPERFECTIONS", 
"BRILLANCE", "GRAIN_PEAU", "RIDES_VISAGE", "MAINS", "PEAU_CORPS", 
"INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE", "INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO", "INTERET_VACANCES", 
"INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT", "AGE_INTERVAL", "ATTENTE_BEAUTE_1", 
"ATTENTE_BEAUTE_2", "MILIEU_VIE", "PROFIL_SELECTIONNE", "NOMBRE_ACHAT", 
"NOMBRE_CADEAU"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

then I used as follow :

```
mydist = dist(DATABASE)
clusters = cutree(hclust(mydist),k=3)

> clusters
  [1] 1 2 3 3 2 2 3 1 1 3 1 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 3 3 2 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 1 3 1 3
 [58] 1 3 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 1 2 2 1 1 3 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 3 3 3 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 1 3 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 3
[115] 1 2 2 1 2 3 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 2 2 1 2 1 1 3 3 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 2 3 3 3 1
[172] 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 3 3 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2
[229] 3 3 1 1 2 1 3 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 3 3 3 2 1 2 3 2 2 1 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2
[286] 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 3 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 3 3 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 2 1 3 1 2 1 2
[343] 1 2 3 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 3 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 2 1 3 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 2 2 1 1 2
[400] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Please Note that the objectif is to compute the inter and intra inertia:
So i need to compute the distance between each centroid and all points that are included in its cluster.

So I need to compute the distance between each centroid and its concerned cluster
to used then for computing the inter and intra inertia.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the centroids as the means of variables,  per cluster, in `DATABASE`.

```
mydist <- dist(DATABASE)
clusters <- cutree(hclust(mydist), k = 3)
## Col means in each cluster
apply(DATABASE, 2, function (x) tapply(x, clusters, mean))
## or
DATABASE$cluster <- clusters # add cluster to DATABASE
# Now take means per group
library(dplyr)
centroids <- DATABASE %>%
        group_by(cluster) %>%
        summarise_all(funs(mean))
## Distance between centroids
dist(centroids[, -1], method = "euclidean")
## Example for distance in cluster 1 (distance between all observations of cluster 1)
DATABASE %>%
        filter(cluster == 1) %>%
        select(-cluster) %>%
        dist()
```

Comment: thank you very much. but how can I compute the distance between each centroid and all other observations included in its cluster??

Comment: Please see my edit. The idea here is to play a bit by filtering `DATABASE` to take the targeted observations and then compute the distance.

Comment: If I well understand, you mean the distance between the centroid of cluster 1 and all observations of the cluster 1 ??

Comment: No, the example is just the distance between all observations of the cluster 1. If you want the distance between the centroid of cluster 1 and all observations of the cluster 1, you have to append the coordinates of centroid to those observations.

Comment: How can I do that with your example please?

Comment: look to your code `DATABASE %>%
        filter(cluster == 1) %>%
        select(-cluster) %>%
        dist()` and `apply(DATABASE, 2, function (x) tapply(x, clusters, mean))`, they give the same output.

Comment: Yes, of course they do and it's normal that's why I said `## or` in the code. This part of the code is about getting the centroids. My comment was about computing distance between centroids or some observations

Comment: so how can we compute the distance between the centroid and observations of clusters?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to specify your k value into 1:3 not just 3

[here is the code and how to find the center (mean)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxAR3.png)

Comment: thank you but I do not know how can I use this to compute the distance between centroids and all grouped observations? in fact i need to compute intra and inter inertia! Look at the edited question